# How do I tell maven where is Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am trying to launch tomcat using following maven command

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

But how do I tell maven that tomcat is located at `D:\Tomcat\`

**pom.xml**

```
 <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
        <!-- MAVEN COMPILER PLUGIN -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    <!-- MAVEN TOMCAT PLUGIN -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>tomcat-server</server>
            <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mvn tomcat7:run` is the command of `tomcat7` maven plugin. To run it you don't need to tell external tomcat server. It automatically download the server from repository and run the project.

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks. One other issue, for some reason it never comes back from `INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]` any ideas?

Comment: @HarisHasan, You can change the port number, if you want. http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

`tomcat7-maven-plugin` should automatically download Tomcat instance. So there is no reason to specify path to your local tomcat.